# c# datagridview need to output decimal value in a cell

Tags: c#, datagridview

i have a code here, but the output in AttendancePercentage keeps converting the result to a whole number.

```
A1 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value);
A2 = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value);
decimal grade = (((A1 + A2) / (decimal)2) * 50) + 50;
double AttendancePercentage = (double)grade * (double).05;
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[19].Value = grade;
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[20].Value = AttendancePercentage;
```

assuming A1 = 1 and A2 = 0. so i need an output of 3.75 but the cell gives 4.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
dataGridView1.Columns['Column Number'].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0.00##";
```

Add your correct column number here: `**Columns['Column Number']**`

Comment: error says. "it does not a definition DefaultCellStyle"

Comment: Try to apply it to whole column

Comment: If you're trying to set the cell format, this is done in the row template, not on the row.

Comment: the output given is 4.00 instead of 3.75
i try to output the answer in messagebox using string("F2") and it shows 3.75 but in datagridview is 4.00